# PassingCars problem in codility using Java

Tags: java, performance

I'm doing codility tasks. I am currently on the Passing Car quest - https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/5-prefix_sums/passing_cars/ ;

One of the performance test, I got "WRONG ANSWER,  got -1794967296 expected -1"

(The performance test name is "large_big_answer 
0..01..1, length = ~100,000")

Other tests were well done

I wonder how to correct this error

Here is my code

```
class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {
        int mul = 0;
        int cnt = 0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i<A.length ; i++){
            if(A[i] == 0) mul++;
            else cnt = cnt+mul;
        }
        if(cnt>1000000000) return -1;
        return cnt;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `BigInteger`. An `int` can't hold such a large value.

Comment: @NicholasK, this problem does not require `BigInteger`. The problem space is such that one bails at < the size that can be handled in an integer.

Comment: oh I see, thank you:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue, as @Nicholas K noted, does have to do with an overflow.

Move the check for the `if (cnt > 1_000_000_000)` into the for loop. The requirements are:

> The function should return −1 if the number of pairs of passing
>   cars exceeds 1,000,000,000.

As such, as soon as the number of pairs exceeds the count, then stop.

So,

```
public int solution(int[] A) {
    int mul = 0;
    int cnt = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i<A.length ; i++){
        if(A[i] == 0) mul++;
        else cnt = cnt+mul;

        if(cnt>1000000000) return -1;
    }

    return cnt;
}
```

Here is a test case that shows the failure:

```
@Test
public void testHalfEach() {
    final int[] inp = new int[100_000];
    final int exp = -1;
    Arrays.fill(inp, 0, 50_000, 0);
    Arrays.fill(inp, 50_000, 100_000, 1);
    validate(inp, exp);
}

private void validate(int[] inp, int exp)
{
    PassingCars prog = new PassingCars();
    int ans = prog.solution(inp);
    assertEquals(exp, ans);
}
```

Changing the location of the check will allow this test to pass.